# Oracle sql remove specific tag from string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want a function to pass a text (varchar2) and a tag name
and return the text with the tag and their child tags removed
Keep only

I don't know how levels of childs there are under tag.

Input :

```
set serverouput on
declare
v_input_str  varchar(4000) := '        <parent1>
            <Message>12ab</Message>
            <CreationDate>02/08/2015</CreationDate>
            <Total>500.45</Total>
            <Collect>
                <Name>Peter</Name>
            </Collect>
        </parent1>';
begin
 dbms_output.put_line(v_input_str);

end;
/


output :
'        <parent1>
            <Message>12ab</Message>
            <CreationDate>02/08/2015</CreationDate>
            <Total>500.45</Total>
            <Collect/>
        </parent1>'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `deleteXML` for this.

Assuming your parameter tag is stored in `tag` variable, do:

```
declare
    v_input_str  clob := '        <parent1>
            <Message>12ab</Message>
            <CreationDate>02/08/2015</CreationDate>
            <Total>500.45</Total>
            <Collect>
                <Name>Peter</Name>
            </Collect>
        </parent1>';
    tag varchar2(20) := 'Collect';
begin
    select deleteXML(xmltype(v_input_str), '//'||tag||'/*').getClobVal() into v_input_str from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_input_str);
end;
```

Output:

```
<parent1><Message>12ab</Message><CreationDate>02/08/2015</CreationDate><Total>500.45</Total><Collect/></parent1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for me . But alignment is not as the initial.

Comment: Why does alignment matter?